# Why this function is attached to global context

Tags: javascript, this, global

When I use `var` keyword to declare any variable it gets declared inside the enclosing scope. However in the code below, I have declared function `c` (inside an object method `a.b`) with `var` keyword and still `this` inside the function `c` is bound to the global object `window`. Why is this?

```
var a = {
        b: function () {
            var c = function () {
                return this;
            };
            return c();
        }
    };

document.write(a.b());  //prints: [object Window]
```

Comment: The `this` value depends on the *context of invocation*, not on the *scope of the variable holding the function.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined by context, not scope.

When you call a function without any context (`context.func()`) as you do there (`c()`), the default context is the default object (which is `window` in browsers) unless you are in strict mode (in which case it is `undefined` instead).

(There are exceptions to this rule, such as `apply`, `call`, `bind`, and `new` but none of them apply here).

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Just curious why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mahesha999/3td3D/1/embedded/js,result) JSFiddle prints `undefined` instead of `global`, though the same in browser works right

Comment: Because you configured JS Fiddle to wrap it in a function and use it as an onload handler: `window.onload=function(){
var context = "global";`

Answer (score 1):

Many people get confused by [this](/questions/tagged/this).  The value [this](/questions/tagged/this) depends on one of 4 methods of invocation.
However, *functional invocation* and [method-invocation](/questions/tagged/method-invocation) cause most of the confusion.
If a function is a member of an object, [this](/questions/tagged/this) is the object itself.

```js
obj.someFunction(); //method invocation
```

If a function is called without context [this](/questions/tagged/this) is the global object (in 'strict mode' [this](/questions/tagged/this) is undefined.)

```
someFunction();  //functional invocation
```

The confusion occurs when a function is called within an object, but not as a member of the object as in anObject.testWithHelper(..);

```js
var testForThis = function(isThis, message) {
    //this can be confusing
    if(this === isThis) 
        console.log("this is " + message);
    else
        console.log("this is NOT " + message);    
};  

//functional invocation
testForThis(this, "global"); //this is global

var anObject = {
    test: testForThis, //I am a method
    testWithHelper: function(isThis, message) {
        //functional invocation
        testForThis(isThis, message + " from helper");
    }
};

//method invocation
anObject.test(anObject, "anObject"); //this is anObject
//method invocation followed by functional invocation
anObject.testWithHelper(anObject, "an object"); //this is NOT anObject from helper
```

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/afrievalt/rryM2/)

If you would like c to return a, you can use [closure](/questions/tagged/closure):

```
var a = {
    b: function () {
        var that = this;
        var c = function () {
            return that;
        };
        return c();
    }
};
```

Or avoid this all together:

```
var getNewA = function() {
    var newA = {};
    newA.b = function() {
        var c = function() {
            return newA;
        };
        return c();
    };    
    return newA;
};

var newA = getNewA();
```

Comment: Overly complicated code. Can simply be rewritten as:

var a = {
    b: function () {
        var c = function () {
            return this;
        };
        return c.call(this);
    }
};