# JS - this reference when using timeOut

Tags: javascript, web, timeout, this

How can I keep the this reference when I use timeOut?

```
var o = {
   f:function(){
     console.log(this)
     setTimeout(this.f,100);
     }
}
o.f();
```

When I run this code the `this` reference is wrong ... what am I missing?

Comment: That code is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: o is an object literal, so your code in general is wrong (this.f = or even f = wont work!)

Comment: what should o be? a function? an object-literal? how do you want to use your code???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass correct "this" context to setTimeout callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this](/questions/tagged/this) depends on the [invocation](/questions/tagged/invocation) method.  For more details see my [other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17425341/2540318).
 f() is a member of o, but o.f is a function passed to timeout and called with functional [invocation](/questions/tagged/invocation). 
This will give you the desired results.

```
var o = {
   f:function(){
     console.log(o)
     setTimeout(o.f,100);
     }
}
o.f();
```

Here is another example of member function called with functional invocation:  See my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afrievalt/sH8bU/)

```
var anObject = {
    test: function(isThis, message) {
        if(this === isThis) 
            console.log("this is " + message);
        else
            console.log("this is NOT " + message);
    }//I am a method
};

//method invocation
anObject.test(anObject, "anObject"); //this is anObject

var aFunction = anObject.test;
//functional invocation
aFunction(anObject, "anObject with aFunction"); //this is NOT anObject with aFunction
aFunction(this, "global with aFunction");//this is global with aFunction
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass paramters into setTimeout, as a third parameter. That way you can pass a reference.

However, if you are trying to create some "object oriented" stuff with new, you shall use a function instead as this:

```
function obj() {
  this.publicFunction = function() {
    console.log("I'm public!");
  };
  var privateFunction = function() {
    console.log("Only accessible from inside this instance!");
  }
}

var objInstance = new obj();
objInstance.publicFunction(); // Logs w/o problem
objInstance.privateFuntion() // Undefined!
```

**EDIT (again):**
But if you're really keen to use a object for some reason, `this` in a object, actually references to the object itself. But since the object is defined as a variable (and in your case global as well), one could directly refer to the name instead of `this`. Here:

```
var o = {
  f: function() {
    console.log(this);  // Will log the object 'o'
    console.log(o);  // Same as above
  }
};

setTimeout(o.f, 100);
```

Comment: Yeah I just remembered.. however, I think OP is out for something "object oriented", which I edited and added an example for.

Comment: I believe there are compatibility issues in passing additional arguments into setTimeout, but I don't know the details. Alternate solutions are using a closure, or Function.prototype.bind